# Get in tpl file name of hook/position

Tags: module, prestashop

i use one module in footer and in specific page.

In footer this module have a layout, but in specific page i want another layout. In file tpl i can change layout by if/else?

I think:

```
{if position == 'footer'}
 codecodecode
{else}
 code
{/if}
```

possible?

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
{if $page.page_name == 'pagename'}
 codecodecode
{else}
 code
{/if}
```

Regards

Comment: no, the page is same. $page.page_name not resolve. I have same module 2 times in same page.

Comment: On which hook is your module plugged?

Comment: displayFooterBefore and displayFooter. And i want layout different for this 2 hook. So i think var {if $hookOrSimilar == 'displayFooterBefore'} .. {else} .. {/if}

Comment: In this case, either in your module you apply a different tpl depending on the hook and you will therefore have two different tpls